# ls command result showing in columns

Tags: ls

When I use ls command, then my results get shown in two columns.

Is there a way I can show all the results in a separate row so it is easier for me to copy and paste in excel.

Current situation doesn't help as when copying the results and pasting in excel, two file name show in one row. I would ideally want each file showing in a separate row so it makes it easier to copy/paste to excel.

Comment: noting that a filename with a newline in it may be mis-represented.

Answer (score 3):

The `-1` option ("minus one") of `ls` will make the utility list the filenames in a single column.  This is described in the `ls` manual.

```
$ touch fileA 'File B' 'file
> with
> newlines'
```

```
$ ls -1
File B
file?with?newlines
fileA
```

Comment: This works, and its really straight forward. Appreciate it.

Comment: GNU `ls` appears to replace newlines; AIX `ls` does not.

Answer (score 3):

It's best to [not parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), although it doesn't really apply in your use case.  You can accomplish what you want using `printf`/shell globbing:

```
printf '%s\n' *
```

Comment: This is very straight forward and I just tried and it works. Thanks for the help.